# Laravel - query depending on user

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I have a scenario in which different users can go to a view blade where they can see posts they have created.

At the minute I'm just passing in all the data, but I'm wondering how to pass data to a view depending on the user.

E.g if I'm a root user I get to see everything so like

```
Post::get()
```

Then

```
return view('someview', compact('post')
```

Which would return the posts

Essentially what Im trying is something like this...

```
if(user->role = their role) then you get query 1 else you get query 2
```

Do you think this is acheivable using conditional query scopes?

UPDATE

Is this a horrible solution?

```
if($user->department == "Loans")
{
    echo "you are from loans FAM";
    $articles = Article::where('department', '=', 'Loans')->get();
} 
else if($user->department == "Digital")
{
    echo "you are from digital FAM";
    $articles = Article::where('department', '=', 'Digital')->get();
} 
else if($user->department == "Consulting")
{
    echo "you are from Consulting FAM";
    $articles = Article::where('department', '=', 'Consulting')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that with a query scope if you wanted to. Something like this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function scopeByUser($query, User $user)
    {
        // If the user is not an admin, show only posts they've created
        if (!$user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return $query->where('created_by', $user->id);
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$posts = Post::byUser($user)->get();
```

---

In response to your update:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function scopeByUser($query, User $user)
    {
        // If the user is not an admin, show articles by their department.
        // Chaining another where(column, condition) results in an AND in
        // the WHERE clause
        if (!$user->hasRole('admin')) {
            // WHERE department = X AND another_column = another_value
            return $query->where('department', $user->department)
                ->where('another_column', 'another_value');
        }

        // If the user is an admin, don't add any extra where clauses, so everything is returned.
        return $query;
    }
}
```

You would use this in the same kind of way as above.

```
Article::byUser($user)->get();
```

Comment: Essentially users from particular departments should only be able to view articles from that department.

Comment: See my updated answer, instead of an `if` statement for each department, you could just pass the department value into the query.

Comment: This feels like a cleaner solution to be honest, I'm going to experiment but I'll be back.

Comment: Can you use AND along with the where?

Comment: Yeah, of course, to do that you can just chain another `where` onto it. I'll update my answer with an example